# Do multiple queries run in parallel or one at a time?

Tags: mysql

When I send multiple queries to MySQL, do they run in parallel or one at a time?

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM a;
SELECT * FROM b;
```

The DB will wait for the first query to complete to run the second one or it will run both at the same time?

Comment: They run one at a time.

Comment: This allows you to make changes in the first query and have the second query depend on the results.